# How many (classes of) objects can YOLO detect?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, darknet

On the yolo website, there are weights pretrained on the coco dataset, which consits of 80 objects/classes, (and I think also weight for voc pascal dataset which consist of 20 classes).
Are there (out there) some weights that have been trained on a dataset with far more classes? I was thinking YOLO can detect thousand of objects and not just 80 as it seem to be the case. Or I'm missing something?

Comment: Regarding your second question, looks like you could do some testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not likely that you'll be able to find weights trained on more or less than 80 classes thought it's reasonably possible. You can recover the full repo [pjreddie/darknet](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet) from GitHub and then change the config file in order to train your model on how-much-you-want classes.

The full description awaits in the repo's README.md file.

Comment: I think also you have to edit the appropriate number of labels in the network architecture in the [yolo] layers of the darknet neural network you will use to train.

Answer (score 1):

The following file from the repo shows possible object names
[class names](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/blob/master/data/9k.names)